# Azure LogAnalytics Parse JSON Array

Tags: azure-log-analytics

I am ingesting some custom logs to Azure LogAnalytics. One of the columns contains nested json objects. I would like to return each nested object to a separate column value.

Was trying the mvexpand statement but have not had any luck.

```
customLog_CL
| extend test = parsejson(target_s)
| mvexpand test
```

The column data looks like below.

```
[ { "id": "00phb49dl40lBsasC0h7", "type": "PolicyEntity", "alternateId": "unknown", "displayName": "Default Policy", "detailEntry": "@{policyType=hello}" }, { "id": "0pri9mxp9vSc4lpiU0h7", "type": "PolicyRule", "alternateId": "00phb49dl40lBsasC0h7", "displayName": "All Users Login", "detailEntry": null } ]
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm in the exact same situation, so hopefully we can share the knowledge. 
I ended up doing something like this, if it's the correct way of doing it, or I have any bugs, I honestly can't tell you right now (still doing my data validation, so I'll update later on), but this should at least get you started.

```
customLog_CL
| mvexpand parsejson(target_s)
| extend Id=target_s["id"]
| extend type=target_s["type"]
| extend OtherId=target_s["alternateId"]
| project Id, type, OtherId
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
datatable(d:dynamic)  
[  
    dynamic(  
        [  
            { "id": "00phb49dl40lBsasC0h7", "type": "PolicyEntity", "alternateId": "unknown", "displayName": "Default Policy", "detailEntry": "@{policyType=hello}" },   
            { "id": "0pri9mxp9vSc4lpiU0h7", "type": "PolicyRule", "alternateId": "00phb49dl40lBsasC0h7", "displayName": "All Users Login", "detailEntry": "" }  
        ]  
    )  
]  
| mv-expand(d)  
| project key = tostring(d['id']), value = d
| extend p = pack(key, value)
| summarize bag = make_bag(p)
| evaluate bag_unpack(bag)
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWG5M.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this fits your requirement.

```
    let hosts_object = parsejson('{"hosts": [ { "id": "00phb49dl40lBsasC0h7", "type": "PolicyEntity", "alternateId": "unknown", "displayName": "Default Policy", "detailEntry": "@{policyType=hello}" }, { "id": "0pri9mxp9vSc4lpiU0h7", "type": "PolicyRule", "alternateId": "00phb49dl40lBsasC0h7", "displayName": "All Users Login", "detailEntry": null } ]}');
    print hosts_object 
    | extend json1 = hosts_object.hosts[0] , json2 = hosts_object.hosts[1]
```

Output for this should be as below

[image]

[Additional Documentation Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/json-data-structures#working-with-objects)

Hope this helps.

Comment: That works, but the results can contain 1 or more objects. So there could be hosts_object.hosts[3] ... to hosts_object.hosts[x]

Comment: Maybe the better question here is how to extract each properties in a json string that has multiple nested json objects. Where the nested members could be an infinite number,

Comment: Sorry for the delay sean, thanks for providing additional information. Let me further check on this and share if I have any findings. Thanks